# Using jQuery UI Autocomplete in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete with ASP.NET like this : 
First I am serializing Good names into string array then I passing Array to source of jQuery UI AutoComplete

```
   //PageLoad
    tadok.Entities.TList<tadok.Entities.Good> GoodEntites = tadok.Data.DataRepository.GoodProvider.GetAll();
    List<string> GoodNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (object item_loopVariable in GoodEntites) {
        item = item_loopVariable;
        GoodNames.Add(string.Format(item.GodTitle));

    }
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Values = serializer.Serialize(GoodNames);
```

MarkUp Code :

```
  var availableTags = <%= Values %>
       $("#txtGoodAutoComplete").autocomplete({
         source: availableTags

          });
```

The object that I am serializing has property with the name ID. How can I serialize ID and storing ID in for example Hidden field on Select item event of autocomplete ?
**Update**
My main challenge is how to Serialize ID ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) event,

If your object is looks like `{'label':'A', 'value':'A', 'ID':'7897975'}`

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
select: function(event, ui) { 
     $('#hiddenField').val(ui.item.ID);//Item is your selected object.
}
});
```

**Update:**

I have never worked on C#. But there should be any built in JSON parser available.

In java i create JSON format like this,

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObject = null;

for(Country country : countries){
                jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("label", country.getName());
                jsonObject.put("value", country.getCode());
                jsonObject.put("id", country.getId().toString());
                jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
            }
String json = jsonArray.toJSONString();//The json string will look like, [{'label':'A', 'value':'A', 'id':'7897925'},{'label':'B', 'value':'B', 'id':'7497975'},{'label':'C', 'value':'C', 'id':'7843975'},{'label':'D', 'value':'D', 'id':'7857975'}]

//Your autocomplete source should return something like the above json string
```

---

By using Javascript Serializer :
First Add a class :

```
public class GoodAutoComplete
{
    public string label;
    public string value;
    public string ID;
}
```

Then Serialize object like this :

```
tadok.Entities.TList<tadok.Entities.Good> GoodEntites = tadok.Data.DataRepository.GoodProvider.GetAll();
List<GoodAutoComplete> GoodItems = new List<GoodAutoComplete>();
foreach (object item_loopVariable in GoodEntites) {
    item = item_loopVariable;
    GoodItems.Add(new GoodAutoComplete {
        ID = item.GodId,
        label = string.Format(item.GodTitle + "{(0)}", item.GodDescrp).Replace("()", ""),
        value = string.Format(item.GodTitle + "{(0)}", item.GodDescrp).Replace("()", "")
    });
}
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Values = serializer.Serialize(GoodItems);
```

Comment: Thank you,
Would you please explain that how can I serialize ID ?
Now In my code I just serialized Good Name .

Comment: How can I serialize my object like {'label':'A', 'value':'A', 'ID':'7897975'}

?

Comment: Look for any JSON library for C#

Comment: @TamilVendhan :
Thank you for your attention. 
I just added C# sample with .NET JavascriptSERIALIZER to your answer.