# How to make a paired input box using autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, autofill

i need to make an autocomplete that will fill the other input boxes as soon as the user selects a account#...i'm using this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/ because it has many features that other autocomplete doesn't have.....i'm using the following parameters..

data: [ ['cutomer01', 001], ['cutomer02', 002], ['cutomer03', 003], ['cutomer04', 004] ]

how can i make a function that will fill all the information as soon as the user selects an account# from an array...i'm just a newbie programmer so please help..

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501993/using-jquery-ui-autocomplete-in-asp-net  Within the select function, write code to populate the data in two other fields.